# Create custom html control in toolbox Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

i want create a custom html control in Visual Studio toolbox:

[image]

For example, if i need create a template for custom table (in toolbox):

```
<table id="table1" data-src="">
    <thead>
        <tr data-id="" data-u="">
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks an sorry my english!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just select your custom html in editor and drag into toolbox pane and custom toolbox item will be created with the text you dragged.