# Sharing custom HTML elements among team members

Tags: visual-studio, custom-controls

In the question: [*Create custom html control in toolbox Visual Studio 2012*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24310522/create-custom-html-control-in-toolbox-visual-studio-2012), the OP gets an answer about creating a custom HTML control in the toolbox of Visual Studio.  I want to do the same thing and then share that with team members.  We are all pulling projects from the same TFS Repository, so I would like to use that if possible.  I hope to achieve something on the level of sharing newly added abbreviations to the team for Intellisense.  I would prefer to not require an install or adding an extension, and especially not creating a DLL that must be referenced or added to the toolbox manually.  Just something that adds these custom HTML controls to the toolbox, with maybe a "Get Latest".